# Are $af(x)$ and $f(x)$ linearly independent if they are restricted to different domains?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, independence

This question arise from a year long project here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409087/is-there-a-treatment-to-relate-the-multiple-scale-analysis-or-scale-separation-t
I'm working out some algebraic descriptions, and need the insights from the numerical analysis to justify the usage of the term "linear independence".

For a function $f(x)$ and a function $af(x)$ where $a\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $a\neq 1$, it was by definition that they were linearly dependent functions. However, one adjusted the definition of the function to different domain.
i.e. $f_1(x)=f(x)$ where $x\in (c_1,c_2)$ and $f_2(y) =f(y)$ where $y\in (c_1,c_3)$.

The first question was whether those two functions, $f_1(x)$ and $af_2(x)$ could still be considered as "linearly dependent functions" or not. Evidently, the answer was $f_1(x)$ and $af_2(x)$ were linearly independent. In fact, the simple linear decomposition in the basis of

> $f_n(x)=nx$ where $x\in [0,n]$ and $x,n\in\mathbb{Z}$

i.e. $\sum_n a_n f_n(x)$ achieved some sort of the Fourier space decomposition with highly non linear effect, when restricted to the finite and discrete domain $[0,N]$ or at least it appeared to be.
( [Why a dozen of first order linear model(lines) add together became fourier function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933633/why-a-dozen-of-first-order-linear-modellines-add-together-became-fourier-funct) ) However, the question was incomplete in the sense that it's "hand waving" to describe such "linear independence" through the numerical graphs.

The second question, however, was harder, that when does such "linear independence" appear, and could it be guaranteed, that for any function $f(x)$, when restricting it to different domain (but coincide like the previous cases, such as $(c_1,c_2)$ and $(c_1,c_3)$), and multiply a nonzero real number $a$ where $a\neq 1$, i.e. $af(x)$.

Does $af(x)$ and $f(x)$ be linearly independent if they are restricted to different domain?

*This was not quite the standard linear algebra, so any thoughts were welcome.

Comment: Technically you should say what vector space these functions live in. Generally a function space has a fixed domain. The answer will depend on how your interpret these functions in the same space.

Comment: @podiki I wasn't quite sure how to say that. Apparently the domain of function $f_1(x)$, $(c_1,c_2)$ and $af_2(x)$, $(c_2,c_3)$ could be extended with some sort of the proportionality involved. Currently I'm looking at the finite and fixed domain to get some insight, but an arbitrary extension of $c_2$ and $c_3$ with some multiplicative difference should work, in fact, that might be one of the condition for the appearance of the "linear independence". For the idea of the vector space it was tricky, with certain functions the difference of real domain and n dimensional domain might vanish.

Comment: How do you add functions with different domains?

Comment: @RobertIsrael A theta function might be involved. But mostly a function was local as $f(x)=0$ when $x\rightarrow$ large, so an extended function could co exist .

Comment: @podiki (Added speculation: though as an attempt to further extend capability to deal with the infinity, I also kept a look out at the application to the statistical manifold. There was a calculation arise where the convergence seemed to distinguish the requirements of the volume, form $r^3$, at low curvature, to $r^2$, with a high curvature. The hope was that the approach might provide some insight of how the "scalar fields" would lead to the "$3$ dimension vector space", and "$2$ dimension" in the case of high curvature. So I kind of intentionally reserved the terminology of vector space.)